# Get count of array and then average in a for each loop

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

This should be easy but for some reason it's escaping me. I have a very simple query and loop here. I didn't add the actual query...but the array of objects in $results. The $totalHits addition works fine. Totaling up the number in $iratings works fine as well. What I am also trying to do is get the count of records in $iratings and print out an average...I just can't seem to get the count part working. How can I modify this to grab the count of $iratings then divide the TotalRating by the count of the number of "$iratings" in the array? if that makes sense?

```
$result = $db->loadObjectList();

// Tally Up the Stats

    $totalHits = 0;
    $totalRating = 0;

    foreach ($result as $item) {
    $ihits = $item->ihits;
    $totalHits = $totalHits + $ihits;
    $iratings = $item->iratings;
    $totalRating = $totalRating + $iratings;
    }

echo ('<br/>Total Hits: '.$totalHits);
 echo ('<br/>Total Rating: '.$totalRating);
```

Comment: Can you put some pseudocode in there with the equation you're trying to perform? It's a little confusing to see it in text form like that.

Comment: Well, from the looks of it, there's one more `$iratings` for each iteration of the loop. So you can just make a nondescript counter to count how many iterations have passed and divide `$totalRating` by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $db->loadObjectList();

// Tally Up the Stats
$totalHits = 0;
$totalRating = 0;
$numIterations = 0;

foreach ($result as $item) {
    $ihits = $item->ihits;
    $totalHits = $totalHits + $ihits;
    $iratings = $item->iratings;
    $totalRating = $totalRating + $iratings;
    $numIterations++;
}

echo ('<br/>Total Hits: '.$totalHits);
echo ('<br/>Total Rating: '.$totalRating);
echo ('<br />Average Rating: ' . ($totalRating/$numIterations));
```

Comment: This worked out quite nicely. With the iterations. Thank you for the assistance.